# How to construct several singleton objects?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I have a singleton, for example:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

class A { 
 private:
  A() {printf("init a unparam A\n");}
  virtual ~A() = default;

 public:
  static A& Inst() { static A u; return u;} 
  void print() {printf("my no = %d\n", no_);}
  int no_ = -1;
};
```

I know this is odd; in most situations, I only need one in my program. However, in some cases, I need several objects in one program, so I added a constructor with an `int` parameter.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

class A { 
 private:
  A() {printf("init a unparam A\n");}
  A(int i) : no_(i) { printf("init a A with no = %d\n", no_);}  // this part is added
  virtual ~A() = default;

 public:
  static A& Inst() { static A u; return u;} 
  static A& Inst(int i) { static A u(i); return u;}   // added
  void print() {printf("my no = %d\n", no_);}
  int no_;
};
```

In main.cpp:

```
int main() {
  A & a = A::Inst();
  a.print();
  A & b = A::Inst(1);
  b.print();
  A & c = A::Inst(2);
  c.print();
}
```

The result is:

```
init a unparam A
my no = 0
init a A with no = 1
my no = 1
my no = 1  // Inst(2) only get the Inst(1) object, why?
```

In my opinion, the first a will create `a` Inst by calling the no parameter constructor, `b` will create one with no=1, `c` create one with no=2.

But the real result is, `b` and `c` share one object.

Could you help on this? How can I make this work?

Comment: `static A u(i);` - This line will only run for the first time you called `static A& Inst(int i)`

Comment: @Ranoiaetep because they share the same variable name u?

Comment: Because it is a static local variable, which means it will only be initialized once.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep ok, thanks. Any advice about this (create several objects)?

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: I don't advice anyone to do it this way, I'm merely providing a solution for OP's question to create multiple object with the singleton pattern.

---

Singleton has been having some bad reputation: [What are drawbacks or disadvantages of singleton pattern? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-are-drawbacks-or-disadvantages-of-singleton-pattern)

Now you want to further break the "Singleton" by making it a "Pluralton", I would only assume it's worse.

---

Nonetheless, the reason you are not getting your expected result is because this line will only run once:

```cpp
static A u(i);
```

This is a static local variable, which mean it will only be initialized for the first time it was called in the function.

---

One way to workaround is by making `static A& Inst(int i)` a templated function, where `i` is being templated, so that each call with a different `i` will generation a new function:

```cpp
template<int I>
static A& Inst() {
    static A u(I); 
    return u; 
}
```

---

Now you can call it like:

```cpp
A & a = A::Inst<1>();
a.print();
A & b = A::Inst<1>();
b.print();
A & c = A::Inst<2>();
c.print();
A & d = A::Inst<2>();
d.print();
```

And it will print:

```cpp
init a A with no = 1
my no = 1
my no = 1
init a A with no = 2
my no = 2
my no = 2
```

Comment: I cannot say strongly enough that this is a terrible idea. Your answer is exactly how i would do this, so +1, but i would do everything in my power not to do this.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I agree, I wouldn't advice anyone to do this either, but this is the most straightforward way I can think of to create multiple object while using the static/singleton pattern.

Comment: but ```int a = 2; A& b = A::Inst<a>();``` won't work.

Comment: @nick It will not, because template parameters must be known at compile time. You can do `constexpr int a = 2; A& b = A::Inst<a>();`.

Comment: thanks @Ranoiaetep, but my ```a``` comes from config reading(which i think it can't be transfer to constexpr), I think i may need rethink my design

Comment: @nick I would suggest to use a `std::map<int, A>` then

Comment: This design is sounding more problematic by the second.